# Scroll only div with scrollBy

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a script that scrolls the window on button click. Works fine, but how do I get this to a target div only? I mean only to scroll a specific div.
I tried to put `getElementById` but I didn't succeed.

Is it even possible with `scrollBy` to do this?

```
<button onmousedown="skrull();" onmouseup="stop();" style="position:fixed;">Click to scroll <3</button>

<p>Some text and line breaks to enable scrolling!</p>

<script>
var skrullInterval;
function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 100);
}
skrull = function skree() {skrullInterval = setInterval(scrollWin, 100);}
function stop() {
    clearInterval(skrullInterval);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why can't you do `scrollTo()`?

Comment: I dont think you can scroll a div, i think that would be called moving it, you would use  something like this? document.getElementById("myBtn").style.top = "100px"; or document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left = "100px";

Comment: I´m not sure I follow your idea. I tried to change scrollBy to scrollTo -> nothings happen.

Comment: divs can be scrolled. what do you mean?
css: height:100px;overflow:auto;
html:a lot of content..

Comment: apologies, you can scroll a div as @Mik_A said

Comment: Try [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). Maybe it what you need.

Comment: I´m not familiar with your suggestion but it doesen't sound like what I am looking for. Can you show me an example how to get it done`?
@Frooey Zanny

Comment: I gave you the link. @Mik_A

Comment: I checked the link. it seems to have nothing to do with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

scrollBy() and scroll() are defined for the window object only. If you want to scroll an element you should set [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) to the desired offset (absolute value, unlike what scrollBy() takes; negative values are silently converted to 0).

```
element.scrollTop = 50;
```

From MDN:

> The Element.scrollTop property gets or sets the number of pixels that
>   an element's content is scrolled vertically.
>
> An element's scrollTop value is a measurement of the distance from the
>   element's top to its topmost visible content. When an element's
>   content does not generate a vertical scrollbar, then its scrollTop
>   value is 0.

Scrolling horizontally is also possible with [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft). Keep in mind this though if you have to deal with right-to-left direction:

> Note that if the element's direction of the element is rtl
>   (right-to-left) then scrollLeft is 0 when the scrollbar is at its
>   rightmost position (at start of the scrolled content) and then
>   increasingly negative as you scroll towards the end of the content.